# Favorite tag location inconvenient

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, design, tag-watching

When browsing the Questions list, the "Favorite Tags" section (on the right) is below the ads. This is challenging for 2 reasons:

1. It requires scrolling just to see, which wastes time and annoys
2. Since the ads load separately from the page sometimes, I begin clicking the favorite tag, only for it to be moved when the ad loads and I end up clicking the ad inadvertently.

When just navigating to SO, and seeing the "Interesting" list, the "Favorite Tags" appear above the ads. Couldn't they always be there?

Comment: Then who will see the ads?

Comment: They will still be plenty visible. As they are when the interesting list is displayed and the Favorites are on top.

Comment: This definitely needs to be addressed. The structure on the side of the Questions should be the same as the structure on the main page.